# passing data to controller in markup

Tags: angularjs

How can I pass data to controller's scope on the markup? 
something like that:

```
<div>
   {{$scope.name = 'Andrew'}} // but I don't want this line to be shown on the browser 
   <input ng-model='name' />
</div>
```

let's say I'm using angular.js in asp.net app and some helper returns json string, 
I need to pass that as an object it to the `$scope`. I could of course create a custom directive and put json string in the attribute,

```
public static string SomeHelper(this HtmlHelper){
    return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize( new { Foo = 'blabla'}).ToString();
} 

<div my-data='@Html.SomeHelper()' >
</div>
```

and then read the attribute and parse the string, and attach the object to the scope:

```
.directive('myData', function(){
    return function(scope, element, attrs){
        $scope.data = JSON.parse(attrs.myData);
    }
 })
```

but maybe there's an easier way

Comment: you need to use ng-init

Comment: Maybe you should think RESTful.